# How to check if multiple windows services are running or not on multiple servers from local machine in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, server, windows-services

I am planning to develope a Application in which I want to check and see if the multiple windows services on multiple Servers `(like svc1,svc2,etc.. on server1 same for server2,..)` are running or not from a local machine.
Also wants to maintain a log in db with server name, service name and there status like below..
[Structure I am looking to store the services info in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC2xV.png)

Currently we are doing it by getting access of all servers one by one remotely which is very common and time consuming way.
We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 OS on all the Servers.
I didn't found any suitable Idea in my research. Appreciate if anyone have any good ideas to achieve this.

Comment: You can query the servers in parallel.This would be a lot faster.

Comment: @RB.: Thanks for immediate response, I will run the query parallel but for that on prior I need to get the info of required services running on multiple servers. How should I get the required services Info running on multiple servers from  local machine?